# C++ Converting String to Integer; Getting Weird outputs?

Tags: c++, string, boost, integer

I have the following code:

```
    {
            line.erase(remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), ::isspace), line.end()); //removes whitespace        
            vector<string> strs;
            boost::split(strs, line, boost::is_any_of("="));
            strs[1].erase(std::remove(strs[1].begin(), strs[1].end(), ';'), strs[1].end()); //remove semicolons 
    if(strs[0] == "NbProducts") { NbProducts = atoi(strs[1].c_str());
            istringstream buffer(strs[1]);
            buffer >> NbProducts; 
    }
```

But whenever I try and output NbProducts I get a really random looking number. The input, by the way, is from a textfile being read with a single line reading:

```
"NbProducts = 1234;"
```

without the quotes.

I know the code is a little sloppy right now. But can anyone see immediatly why I might be getting weird integers in the place of "NbProducts?"

Comment: Are you trying to parse a text grammar? You should probably [be XY-phrasing your question a little](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using boost:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10a0fdd0d346e60e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
#include <sstream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::istringstream buffer("NbProducts = 1234;");

    int NbProducts;
    if (buffer >> qi::phrase_match(
            qi::lit("NbProducts") >> "=" >> qi::int_ >> ";", 
            qi::space, NbProducts))
    {
        std::cout << "Matched: " << NbProducts << "\n";
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Not matched\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Matched: 1234
```

---

In case you're wondering why you'd do such a thing, instead of doing all the string handling manually: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8480e7c0a64a9d70)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
typedef qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double> > sdouble_;
typedef boost::variant<int, double, std::string> value;

int main()
{
    std::istringstream buffer("NbProducts = 1234; SomethingElse = 789.42; Last = 'Some text';");

    std::map<std::string, value> config;

    if (buffer >> std::noskipws >> qi::phrase_match(
            *(+~qi::char_("=") >> '=' >> (qi::lexeme["'" >> *~qi::char_("'") >> "'"] | sdouble_() | qi::int_) >> ';'),
            qi::space, config))
    {
        for(auto& entry : config)
            std::cout << "Key '" << entry.first << "', value: " << entry.second << "\n";
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Parse error\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Key 'Last', value: Some text
Key 'NbProducts', value: 1234
Key 'SomethingElse', value: 789.42
```